# How to check in Java an IP address matches the server running the application

Tags: java, network-programming, ip

The goal is checking that an application is running on a given server. Some kind of license check.

Ideally the license will contain an IP address, and some Java code will check this IP address is the one where the Java process is running.

Think about NAT, clouds, nodes, virtual machines and all little beasts.

Any hints, ideas are welcomed

Answer (score 1):

`InetAddress.getLocalHost().getAddress()` gives you the IP address of localhost.

Comment: You can have several IP addresses per server, this might not work (think NAT)

Comment: I think you should specify in some more detail who wants to check what.

Answer (score 1):

To check that an `InetAddress` is associated with the current machine, you have to check:

1. If the address is a special synonym for localhost:

   `address.isAnyLocalAddress() || address.isLoopbackAddress()`
2. If the adress is an IP address assigned to a local interface:

   `NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(address) != null`

Answer (score 0):

Run the license app as a server socket and the app as client socket. The server connects and requests permission to run or terminate. Client received the packet knows which server ip the request is coming from and replies with an OK or NOT OK. based on this server runs or terminates. you may want to use some smartness there to ensure people cant emulate your licensing server.